# Matching file extension with used programing language

Tags: python, json, match, file-extension

I have a large dataset in a JSON format that contains the file extensions of different programming files. I would like fill the entry "language" with the name of the related programming language in order to make it possible to search the data-set for specific languages. The dataset looks like this:

```
data = [{"ID":".","doc_path":".","doc_type":".py","language":#insert language here}{"ID":".","doc_path":".","doc_type":".m","language":#insert language here}...]
```

Is there a way to derive the language name automatically from the doc_type?

Comment: I think this is a case of [the X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would help if you explained why you're trying to implement what you're describing (i.e. what problem do you aim to solve with your program?).

Comment: I'd be surprised if file extensions were unique among all programming languages. Surely there are at least two languages that use, I don't know, `.h` or something.

Comment: @ResetACK thanks for the hint. I will reformulate my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in mapping object for this in the stdlib. You *might* be able to find some 3rd-party module that provides it (e.g. on PyPI).